# Triple Integral Limits Question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The equivalent integral to $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}xyz \ \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

The limits I got were $\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r^2}^{r}zr^3\cos\theta \sin \theta  \ \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$

Is this right?

Comment: Your second integral is not right.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have it right .

For the volume of the regeion you have the correct integral $$ \displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}xyz \ \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

And changing to cylindrical coordinate you have the correct integral.
$$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r^2}^{r}zr^3\cos\theta \sin \theta  \ \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: i have edited my question, is it right now?

Comment: Yes. It is perfect. congratulations!

Comment: I have edited my answer as well.